# How can I bind an asp:chart (from microsoft) to a Dictionary<string,string>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, datasource

I'm using the MS chart controls for ASP.Net and I can't figure out binding.
Does any one have information on how can I bind an asp:chart (from microsoft) to a dictionary?

Comment: Have you tried binding the words Key and Value as fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var employees = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {10,"Employee 1"},{20,"Employee 2"},{30,"Employee 3"}
};

Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> employee in employees)
    Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(employee.Value, employee.Key);
```

**Output:**

[image: Chart]